# Getting an http response that is impossible to occur in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a form that I am processing in django. It is processing the form correctly but after the processing is done, it is throwing an http response error which could not possibly be happening...

here is the form:

```
# create a new expense form - group
class CreateExpenseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    split_choices = (('1', 'even'),
                      ('2', 'individual'))
    split = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=split_choices
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        fields = ['location', 'description', 'amount', 'split']
```

here is the view :
I am going to break where the error is happening:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateExpenseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            location = cd['location']
            description = cd['description']
            amount = cd['amount']
            split = cd['split']
            reference = generate_number()
            for member in members:
                if member.user.username in request.POST:
                    new_expense = Expense.objects.create(
                        user = member.user,
                        group = group,
                        location = location,
                        description = description,
                        amount = amount,
                        reference = reference,
                        created_by = user,
                    )
            print('all exepense accounted for')
```

'all expenses accounted for' is printing in the terminal then it throws the error

now with the form, there are only two choices that split can be which are 1 and 2

I am selecting option 1 (even) so the split should be one, but none of the print message are displaying...

```
            if split == 1:
                print('even split')
                print(groupid)
                print(groupname)
                return redirect('even_expense', groupid = groupid, groupname = groupname)
            if split == 2:
                print('individual splut')
                return redirect('test')
```

it is not printing any error so the http response error has to happen in the section above.

```
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return redirect('test')
    else:
        form = CreateExpenseForm()
        parameters = {
            'form':form,
            'members':members,
        }
        return render(request, 'groups/create_expense.html', parameters)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
field = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, coerce=int)
```

Adding **coerce=int** will convert the value to the type you want, here the type is **int**.